# Where can I find the latest Paper Cuts

Tags: usability, one-hundred-paper-cuts

I remember seeing in launchpad and the Ubuntu wiki a page where I could see the 100 paper cuts that were worked on for the latest Ubuntu (I think it was 9.10 or 10.04 in that time). Do the 100 paper cuts still exist and if so are they available to see for Ubuntu 11.10 (To see which paper cuts were solved) and 12.04 (To see which paper cuts will be worked on).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The paper cuts targeted to the 13.04 cycle can be found [here](https://launchpad.net/hundredpapercuts/raring).

The main page is here https://launchpad.net/hundredpapercuts and each release is listed under https://launchpad.net/hundredpapercuts/.

For example:

- https://launchpad.net/hundredpapercuts/natty
- https://launchpad.net/hundredpapercuts/oneric
- https://launchpad.net/hundredpapercuts/precise